Could replacing capacitor have caused a leak in my whole house AC unit?
My 10-year old whole house AC unit has a leak.  The capacitor was replaced 10 months ago.  Could the act of replacing have caused the leak?

Does it matter? Even if that's what happened you won't have any way to prove it. You're on the hook unless you happen to have a warranty covering leaks.

Anything is possible if you have a technician who doesn't know what they are doing.
However, a capacitor is a simple electrical component and normally can be replaced without working on the refrigerant system in any way. Arguably any appliance technician could replace an air conditioning system capacitor without any special training, whereas working on the refrigerant loop requires special training and equipment. I think the chance of the two issues being related is extremely small.
If the leak happened within a week of the capacitor replacement then there is much more of a chance they were connected. But 10 months is a very long time.
Also keep in mind that while we all want (especially me!) our appliances to last forever, things start breaking on major appliances around the 10 year mark, so two separate problems within the 10th year is not unusual.

Thank you for your reply.
